# Получение объекта с чужого сервера JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Встал вопрос: допустим с чужого сайта по ссылке www.example.com/example отдается объект {"x":3}. Неужели нельзя получить этот объект с помощью javascript без авторизаций и плясок с бубнами? Почему просто пройдя по ссылке я спокойно вижу этот объект, но не могу его стянуть в свой сценарий и работать с ним? Есть ощущение, что я чего-то не понимаю.

Пробовал так:

```js
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', 'https://example.com/example');
alert( x.responseText );
```

Как сильно я далек от истины?

Comment: Почитайте статью: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Видел, не подходит, на чужом сайте/сервере я ничего не смогу добавить.

Comment: @enki, есть довольно много методов обхода этой политики - от `JSONP` до фреймов и прочего. Google it!

Comment: JSONP я так понимаю работает, если сервер посылает функцию, а у меня безымянный объект. Загружу я его в теги скрипта, выгружу в страницу, а забрать как?

Answer (score 1):

[Политика ограничений других доменов, протоколов и даже портов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).
Из соображений безопасности.
Хороший вариант решения приведен в статье, рекомендованной @MasterAlex - [click me](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).
Ограничения не дают кому не лень инжектиться в Ваш код и делать гадости или даже взламывать.